# Non greedy positive lookbehind in regex

Tags: regex

I have following text

```
# Heading Level 1\\r\\n## Heading Level 2\\r\\n### Heading 
Level 3\\r\\n#### Heading Level
4\\r\\n##### Heading Level 5\\r\\n###### Heading Level 6\\r\\nHeading Level 13
Alternate\\r\\n======================\\r\\n
```

I need to match `Heading Level 13 Alternate` (basically anything b/w newline and ===

I have tried following

`(?<=\\\\r\\\\n)?.*?(?=\\\\r\\\\n=+)`

But the problem is that my regex is being greedy with \r\n and is going all the way back. I want to stop it at first \r\n

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
(?<=\\\\r\\\\n)(?:(?!\\\\r\\\\n)[\w\W])*?(?=\\\\r\\\\n=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMmrZG/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\\\\r\\\\n)` - a location immediately preceded with `\\r\\n` string
- `(?:(?!\\\\r\\\\n)[\w\W])*?` - (a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)) any char, zero or more but as few as possible occurrences, that is not the starting point for a `\\r\\n` char sequence
- `(?=\\\\r\\\\n=)` - a location immediately followed with `\\r\\n=` string.

Here, `[\w\W]` is used instead of `.` in order to match across lines (`.` does not match line break chars by default, but that depends on the regex flavor). You might also use `s` flag or its `(?s)` inline version (in Onigmo/Ruby, replace `s` with `m`) with a dot.

Comment: thx.. could you please explain this part `(?:(?!\\\\r\\\\n)[\w\W])*?`

Comment: @nitinsh99 This is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat).